# Python part of script does not start from webpage

Tags: php, python, shell, html

I have a webpage on a linux NAS, with webserver and php running.
I want to start a script from de server, to write data to a database.

When i am on the new69.php (the website in question)
I have the 
for example :

`$uptime = exec('uptime');echo $uptime;`
(and this works)

So i have a connection.

Then i do with a if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['verzenden'])) {
 $output1 = exec('whoami');
 exec('/share/MD0_DATA/Qweb/sqlite/AllesNaardDB.sh');
 } else {

    echo "Nog lekker niets gedaan.";
```

`Whoami` in the is statememt gives the username "httpdusr",
So the if statement gets reached and works.

Now the exec statement when i do:

It has to execute the AllesNaardDB.sh
which contains:

```
cd /share/MD0_DATA/Qweb/sqlite
echo "Wasmachine"
python2.6 wasm_util_sql.py [param]
echo "alles gegeven"
exit 0
```

Nothing is shown or done.

But when i do:

```
$output = exec('/share/MD0_DATA/Qweb/AllesNaardDB.sh');
echo "<pre> $output </pre>";
```

I get the als line of the script in the variable $output,
**"alles gegeven"**.

At first i tought that it could be something to do with the rights.
So i (switched user with) su to "httpdusr" and script in putty gets executed fine.

I also made another script ff.sh with "ls -l" to execute and everything works.
Also i treid 
passthru(), 
system(),
shell_exec.
The only improvements are that with system() and passthru(), the "echo "Wasmachine""
appeared on te website.

I don't get why the python jobs don't get started ?

I worked a little further, but could it be that there are some sqlite3 command which are user dependent ?

Like that i could execute some write action to the database as admin, but not as the httpdusr ?

Comment: Perhaps it is not finding the python2.6 command. Try to use the absolute path and tell if this works.

Comment: Did you try the same absolute path directly from shell?

Comment: Yes i did the complete path. And I ran a python script straight from the webpage. And that worked also. So only from al shell script it will not work??

Comment: I am sorry. It's a strange effect you have and I am not able to help you.

Comment: I know, but thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a prblem with a path in the python script, which is writing to the database.
It uses a different path when it is started from the webpage (MD0_DATA/Qweb/) then wen it is started from the shell script (MD0_DATA/Qweb/sqlite)

*i dit not solvend the problem yet, but understand it.
Everybody thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `#!/bin/sh` to the top of the script and make sure it's `chmod a+x`.

Comment: I added the line(was not there, good call) and chmod/chown the script. But it did not helped.

Comment: if you are on linux, try running this from the command line and see if it outputs anything : `php -r "echo exec('/share/MD0_DATA/Qweb/AllesNaardDB.sh');"`

Comment: The command php is globaly not found. Then i tried it with full path, And this works !!! Very interesting!!